# how to hold a changed colour of the button which clicked by user

Tags: java, android

in my app there are three buttons `yes no maybe`. here I changed the colour of the button when user click any button that colour changed. when user clicks the button it stored as 1 0 2 in table based on user select the button. but when I go some other option in app and return back to this the buttons are as it normal. here that should be highlighted which is selected by user.

the following code for `yes no maybe button`

```
yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // highlight the button when clicked
        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //If user clicks yes button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 1 for event user
        final int response = 1;
        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
});
noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //If user clicks no button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as 0 for event user
        final int response = 0;
        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();
        userMO.setIsAttending(response);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
});
maybeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yesBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        noBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        maybeBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        responseLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //If user clicks maybe button in invitation response layout,response would be stored as  for event user
        final int response = 2;
        userMO.setIsAttending(response);
        final long eventId = eventMOs.get(position).getEventId();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                return userDelegate.updateEventUserRelationShipMapping(userMO, eventId);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
});
```

this `yes no maybe` layout shows when `event` is clicked
here events are list view when I clicked single event it should show for each event what I have clicked

Comment: add selector in button

Comment: can u pls explain in breif

Comment: you have to save the status somewhere like database or shared preference and when you are coming in activity again then you have to bind it with the view.

Answer (score 0):

use selectors for states like this hope this will help you...

create btn_stae.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hidden_bg" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_round" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/border" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active" />
</selector>
```

active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/green_dark" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />


</shape>
```

border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/button_bg_stroke"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/button_bg" />


</shape>
```

bg_round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/switch_thumb_normal_material_dark" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/background_material_light" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

hidden_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/bg" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/light" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />


</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the requirement is only for save the 3 buttons state you can use sharedpreference to save the selected button value.
2. If yes is selected save value as 0, No is selected save as 1, May be clicked save 2.

Code to save value in sharedpreference. Write the similar code on your button click listeners.

```
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   
       int clickedButton = sharedpreferences.getInt("clicked_btn", 1); //1 is the default value.
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("clicked_btn", 0); //value will be 0 or 1 or 2
editor.commit();
```

3. And get the saved value on next time in activity onResume() method like this

   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          int clickedButton = sharedpreferences.getInt("clicked_btn", 1); //1 is the default value.
4. Add switch case and change button color of last saved button based on the clickedButton value.
5. Switch case should be like this

   ```
   switch (clickedButton)
   {
   case 0:  //here change yes button color
       break;
   case 1:  //here change no button color
       break;
   case 2:  //here change may be button color
       break;           
   default: //here default button color for saved button id
       break;
   }
   ```

Hope this will help for you.